# Python Script calling a shell script via os.system() exit code 256 instead of 1. Why?

Tags: shell, python

I am writing a Python Script handling the exit codes of different shell scripts.

When i call the shell script via command prompt and ask for the exit code with `echo $?`, I get a 1.
When I call the shell script via the python script, I assume the value will be `1`, but instead it turns out to be 256.

What happened?

This is my shell Script for testing a Camera:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#cam.sh

if [ -r /dev/video0 ]
then
    #taking a picture
    ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/dev0 -ss 0:0:2 -frames 1 ~/Desktop/testbild.jpg 2>/dev/null
    #showing a stream 
    timeout 10s vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --no-audio --no-video-title-show
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

And my Python call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#exitcodetest.py

import os

command = "sh ~/Desktop/cam.sh"
camera = os.system(command)
print(camera)
```

Why?

Comment: It is the return-code of `sh`. Is `sh` bash? Try `command = "~/Desktop/cam.sh"` (with `chmod +x` first.

Comment: the script is already runnable by chmod +x. Thanks!

Comment: file extensions are bad form, and so is having the caller specify the interpreter.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I don't really understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: AGeß instead of `sh ~/Desktop/cam.sh` stop specifying a shell and just run the script directly, `~/Desktop/cam.sh`

Comment: Like @roaima said, but now there is no need for the extra (Hungarian notation) characters at the end of the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `os.system` doesn't return exitcode but waitstatus. To convert it to return code you need to use `os.waitstatus_to_exitcode` (or `os.WEXITSTATUS` for older Python versions).

```
In [2]: os.WEXITSTATUS(256)                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[2]: 1
```

See python documentation for [os.waitstatus_to_exitcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.waitstatus_to_exitcode) and [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for more details. And also `man system` and `man waipid` for more details on wait status.

Also if you need some more "user friendly" way of running commands/programs from Python, I recommend using the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using `camera = os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(command))` now and get the assumed 1 :)